# Approve and Reject in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know this question is not that hard but I'm new to asp.net mvc3 and I don't have an idea how to do this.
 I created a simple CRUD function in my controller. Now in my edit I changed the textbox to a two radio button Approve and Reject. Now my question is how could I let my edit get the value of the radio button that I choose? Here are the value of my radio buttons in my View>Edit

My VIEW>EDIT

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Approve" />Approve
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Reject"/>Reject
</div>
```

[image]

Here is the Edit in my Controller I don't know what to modify here.. :(

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Leave leave = db.Leaves.Single(l => l.leave_id == id);
        return View(leave);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Leave leave)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Leaves.Attach(leave);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(leave, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(leave);
    }
```

Here is the model of my leave

[image]

Comment: Show how looks your Leave class

Comment: What is the type of Status?

Comment: at first i use a textbox for it so I assign varchar as its type anyhow the type doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Html.RadioButtonFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "Approve") Approve
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "Reject") Reject
```

instead of

```
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Approve" />Approve
<input type="radio" name="action" value="Reject"/>Reject
```

It depends from the type of your Status.
If it's bool than DevDave's example should work fine.
If it's string - than my first example should be ok.
But if it's int with values 0 for Reject and 1 for Approve - you should use something like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "1") Approve
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "0") Reject
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting but how about the edit in my controller? How could I let it know which button did I choosed. thanks.

Comment: You just submit the form and post values on controller action.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I was now able to understand it. :) I was able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a bool value for Status:

```
<label for="approve">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "True", new { id = "approve" })
Approve
</label>

<label for="reject">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Status, "False", new { id = "reject" })
Reject
</label>
```

**Edit**: It is bad practice to expose your db object, you should use a view model that has the relevant properties from your db object and then you can map between the two when saving/loading.

I.e. return LeavesViewModel to view, but convert your LeavesViewModel into db oject on save.

In the example provided, this should directly map to the Leave object that is passed into your Post method, assuming it is a bool value. Debug and you should see the value come back true or false depending on the option you choose.

It may also work if Status is an Enum with more than two (i.e. bool) options but I have not tried that before.

So in your edit view, wrap your radio buttons and other parts of the form in:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ControllerName")) {
   ..your stuff

   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting but how about the edit in my controller? How could I let it know which button did I choosed. thanks.